# MDX - Average over the whole time period, even when no data exists

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I have a fact table with 1 row for each day. Example:

```
ID  Date     Value
1   20190101 10
1   20190102 15
2   20190101 31
```

If I take a simple Value average in SSAS cube I get:

```
ID Average <Formula>
1  12.5    (10+15)/2
2  15.5    31/2
```

As I understand, 15.5 is there because in total there are 2 days in the scope as only two days exist in the fact data when I select the whole month.

However, I need to calculate a **monthly** average instead. It should check that there are 31 days in that month (based on Date dimension) and get this result:

```
ID Average <Formula>
1  0.8     (10+15)/31
2  1       31/31
```

So far I've tried to create some "fake rows" if my data, for example I've tried to create rows with Value = 0 for dates 20190103-20190131 for ID=1.

This works, it forces the calculation for ID=1 to always take all days in the period, but it messes up my other calculations in the cube.

Any other ways to force average calculation **in SSAS multidimensional cube** to always calculate for the entire month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do the calculation in the Cube, you can use the [Descendants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/descendants-mdx) function on your Date dimension

For eg., the following gives the number of days in a month using the [AdventureWorks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure) sample

```
WITH MEMBER Measures.DayCount AS 
    Descendants
    ( 
        [Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember,   
        [Date].[Calendar].[Date],
        LEAVES  
    ).Count

SELECT [Measures].[DayCount] ON 0,
        [Date].[Calendar].[Month].ALLMEMBERS ON 1 
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, managed to find an example where this is used together with a measure, will try this.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
select id, eomonth(date) as eom,
       sum(value) * 1.0 / day(eomonth(date)) as average
from t
group by id, eomonth(date);
```

`EOMONTH()` returns the last day of the month.  You can extract the day to get the number of days in the month.

The `* 1.0`is because SQL Server does integer division.  Your numbers look like integers, but if you are getting 15.5, then you actually have `numeric`s or something other than an integer.

Comment: I'm interested in how this can be calculated in SSAS cube / MDX, if there is any other ways to do it except adding fake data.

Comment: @Alex_404 . . . What do you mean "adding fake data"?  This seems like the simplest way to do what you are asking for.

Comment: yes, this works for SQL but I just could not translate this solution into MDX, so I've tried adding rows with Value=0 for all days missing and taking simple AVG(). This worked in cube for AVG() but messed up other calculations.